# Do I need to minify my js file if i am doing winjs development?

Tags: winjs

Is it possible for someone to look at the javascript code of a winjs app? Is it recommended to minify the js code for a winjs application? any other best practices?

I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f2b01fa4-0639-468f-b5d3-405e80371ece/how-to-secure-application-source-code-in-winjs) link but it did not help much. It refers to a sticky post. I looked at the sticky posts but they appeared to be unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minification is just one strategy you can employ, depending on your needs. I wrote about this and other options on my blog: http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2013/04/04/protecting-your-code/.

Comment: thanks. to answer my first question, yes it is possible to inspect the js code of a winjs app by unzipping the .appxupload file.

Comment: Yes. This is also possible even with .NET languages, because compiled IL in an app package can be put through a reverse compiler. Compiled C++ would be the hardest to reverse engineer, but not impossible. The only truly secure way is to keep things on a secure server.

Answer (score 0):

While in development use the unminified file so it easier to debug, on production it is recommended to use the minified file, and also as the sticky post said You can also protect your more sensitive algorithms and business logic from reverse engineering by putting them on a server and not in your app.